# iOS Keyboard Extension detect tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I am building a custom keyboard and adding a scroll view of images to it. I am trying to detect taps but it is not working. Any suggestions? I have tried adding a action to a UIButton within the scroll view as well with no luck. This code displays the images in a scrollview fine however it won't detect taps. CODE BELOW

```
  @interface KeyboardViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *_picHolderArray;

    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *nextKeyboardButton;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *keyboardBackground;
@end

@implementation KeyboardViewController

- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    [super updateViewConstraints];
        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.keyboardBackground.delegate = self;
    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.nextKeyboardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

    [self.nextKeyboardButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Next Keyboard", @"Title for 'Next Keyboard' button") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.nextKeyboardButton sizeToFit];
    self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.nextKeyboardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(advanceToNextInputMode) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.nextKeyboardButton];

    NSLayoutConstraint *nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.nextKeyboardButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.nextKeyboardButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
    [self.view addConstraints:@[nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint, nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint]];
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    CGRect frame;

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 162);
    else
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216);

    self.keyboardBackground = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 180)];



    _picHolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    UIImage* backgroundImage =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyBack.jpg"]
                               resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(100, 0, 0, 0) ];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.keyboardBackground.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [backgroundImage drawInRect:self.keyboardBackground.bounds];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.keyboardBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
    int _x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //load button size and pass in array for titles
        UIImageView *imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_x,45, 200, 120)];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.jpg"];
        [imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
        [imageView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
        [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        // Create colored border using CALayer property
        [[imageView layer] setBorderColor:
         [[UIColor colorWithRed:(5.0/255.0) green:(108.0/255.0) blue:(182.0/255.0) alpha:1] CGColor]];
        [[imageView layer] setBorderWidth:1.75];
        [_picHolderArray addObject:imageView];

        [self.keyboardBackground addSubview:_picHolderArray[i]];
        _x += imageView.frame.size.width + 60;
    }

    //self.shell.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.keyboardBackground.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
   //self.keyboardBackground.pagingEnabled = YES;
    //self.keyboardBackground.scrollEnabled = YES;

    self.keyboardBackground.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_x, 180);


    [self.view addSubview:self.keyboardBackground];
}
- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIView *tappedView = [gesture.view hitTest:[gesture locationInView:gesture.view] withEvent:nil];
    NSLog(@"Touch event on view: %@",[tappedView class]);
}

/**********************************************************************
 *
 * scrollViewDidScroll: allows us to know which camera is viewed.
 *
 **********************************************************************/
#pragma mark - ScrollView Delegates
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int  _index = ((int)(scrollView.contentOffset.x)/320);
    NSLog(@"%d",_index);
}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"HEEERE");
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

- (void)textWillChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

- (void)textDidChange:(id<UITextInput>)textInput {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    UIColor *textColor = nil;
    if (self.textDocumentProxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearanceDark) {
        textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    [self.nextKeyboardButton setTitleColor:textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see NSLogs of your keyboard extension if you run that target.

You were most likely running your base app as your Xcode target. Since your debugger is then attached to your base app rather than your extension, NSLogs will not be seen in the Console.